# Angular keypress interfering with form inputs

Tags: angularjs

I don't want the function to fire when input fields have focus (see jsfiddle)

```
myApp.directive('keypressEvents', ["$document", "$rootScope", function ($document, $rootScope) {
function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    //console.log($document, $element, $scope, $attrs);
    $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        //console.log(e.key);
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3) {
            //alert(key);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
        }
    });
}

return {
    link: link
};
}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28cm90v9/

Is there a way to set an If() conditional if a text input field has focus?

Comment: What's the point of this directive then? How can an input field receive `keypress` events and not be focused?

Comment: Building a hotbar for a scheduling website. Here's an example of a hotbar. I'm thinking ngFocused might be there answer. Thank you for your question. https://parttimecoregaming.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/hotbars.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use these on form fields that require numbers

```
ng-blur="blurred()" ng-focus="focused()"
```